# VS.NET Load Testing - pass site URL via parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests

I'm building VS.NEt 2010 Load Test solution.

Everything works really good except one thing. When I record .webtest script - it grabs the site domain name, like so:

http://test1/page1
http://test1/page2

So the test1 is hardcoded in the script.

What I would like to do is to run same load test again different test environment - the goal is to compare two environment without rewriting the recording.

I see that Run Settings has "Context Parameters" - is this it?

Comment: In Run Settings - add Content Parameters; then use that in .webtest file - use it as {{parametername}} - works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

For for a **recorded .webtest**, [this article](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/06/30/randomizing-input-data-for-visual-studio-load-tests/) shows using the context parameters with the {{parameterName}} syntax for form parameters, and can indeed be used for the server name.

From inside a **coded test** (which inherits from **WebTest**), you can access it with:

```
this.Context["KeyName"]
```